# How can I see LeakCanary?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I am trying to solve these leaks. But I have no idea which one is the problem.

1.

```
┬───
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ android.os.Looper class
│    Leaking: NO (Thread↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
│    ↓ static Looper.sMainLooper
├─ android.os.Looper instance
│    Leaking: NO (Thread↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ Looper.mThread
├─ java.lang.Thread instance
│    Leaking: NO (the main thread always runs)
│    Thread name: 'main'
│    ↓ Thread.threadLocals
│             ~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 2.2 kB in 69 objects
│    ↓ ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.table
│                                 ~~~~~
├─ java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry[] array
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 2.1 kB in 68 objects
│    ↓ ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry[].[21]
│                                         ~~~~
├─ java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 28 B in 1 objects
│    ↓ ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry.value
│                                       ~~~~~
├─ android.animation.AnimationHandler instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 29.7 MB in 54029 objects
│    ↓ AnimationHandler.mAnimationCallbacks
│                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.util.ArrayList instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 29.7 MB in 54025 objects
│    ↓ ArrayList.elementData
│                ~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 29.7 MB in 54024 objects
│    ↓ Object[].[0]
│               ~~~
├─ android.animation.ValueAnimator instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 875 B in 28 objects
│    ↓ Animator.mListeners
│               ~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.util.ArrayList instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 60 B in 2 objects
│    ↓ ArrayList.elementData
│                ~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 40 B in 1 objects
│    ↓ Object[].[0]
│               ~~~
├─ android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator$AnimatorEventListener instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 368 B in 12 objects
│    ↓ ViewPropertyAnimator$AnimatorEventListener.this$0
│                                                 ~~~~~~
├─ android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 356 B in 11 objects
│    ↓ ViewPropertyAnimator.mView
│                           ~~~~~
├─ androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView instance
│    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
│    Retaining 1.2 kB in 19 objects
│    View is part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mID = R.id.iv_energy
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    mContext instance of com.example.components.ui.result.
│    ResultVer2Activity with mDestroyed = true
│    ↓ View.mContext
╰→ com.example.components.ui.result.ResultVer2Activity instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.example.components.ui.result.ResultVer2Activity received
​     Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     Retaining 18.4 MB in 13058 objects
​     key = dc4c55d5-5d97-4091-b7ad-0cd2a49f4d09
​     watchDurationMillis = 6804
​     retainedDurationMillis = 1799
​     mApplication instance of com.example.MyApplication
​     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper

METADATA

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 30
Build.MANUFACTURER: Google
LeakCanary version: 2.6
App process name: com.example
Count of retained yet cleared: 12 KeyedWeakReference instances
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=8027,misses=155358,hitRate=4%]
RandomAccess[bytes=7640055,reads=155358,travel=107845991097,range=28570681,size=
41968225]
Heap dump reason: 7 retained objects, app is visible
Analysis duration: 87264 ms
```

2. 

```
│ GC Root: Global variable in native code
│
├─ android.widget.Toast$TN instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 524.3 kB in 16111 objects
│    ↓ Toast$TN.mPresenter
│               ~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.widget.ToastPresenter instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 522.4 kB in 16104 objects
│    mContext instance of com.example.components.ui.exam.
│    ExamEntryActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    ↓ ToastPresenter.mContext
│                     ~~~~~~~~
╰→ com.example.components.ui.exam.ExamEntryActivity instance
     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.example.components.ui.exam.ExamEntryActivity received
     Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
     Retaining 354.3 kB in 12305 objects
     key = dce008b9-d99a-4dfa-be4f-a5b0ae8917cb
     watchDurationMillis = 57521
     retainedDurationMillis = 52002
     mApplication instance of com.example.MyApplication
     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper

METADATA

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 30
Build.MANUFACTURER: Google
LeakCanary version: 2.6
App process name: com.example
Count of retained yet cleared: 2 KeyedWeakReference instances
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=10382,misses=177073,hitRate=5%]
RandomAccess[bytes=10509449,reads=177073,travel=81077330786,range=32700295,size=
48659081]
Heap dump reason: 6 retained objects, app is visible
Analysis duration: 16424 ms
```

How can I read this trace and fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first leak is happening because something is setting up an animator on the R.id.iv_energy ImageView. The animator should be canceled when that view is detached, but it's not, the animator is still running and holding on to the ImageView.

The second one is happening because a toast is being held by a native ref. Canceling the toast might help, or creating the toast with the application context instead of activity context.